# Adding shadows in circle svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-filters

Given the code below:

1. What are actually x&y parametes in filter element ?
2. Can x&y parameters in filter element be kept on changing by javascript ? I can define the changing x&y parameters of filter element  in house() as per the changes in variable in var h &var k.
3. Make the necessary changes in code to meet the necessity.

```
<body style="background:black;margin:0px" onmousemove="house(event)">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="105%" height="105%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="20" dy="20" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="offOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle r="25" id="circle" fill="yellow" filter="url(#f1)"></circle>
</svg>
<script>
function house(e)
{
    var h=e.clientX;
    var k=e.clientY;
    var ball=document.getElementById("circle");
    var r=ball.getAttribute("r");
    ball.setAttribute("cx",h);
    ball.setAttribute("cy",k);

}
</script>
```

Comment: @pswg Whats the edit?

Comment: Just formatting. You can click the link above my name to see on the question to see exactly what the edit was.

Answer (score 0):

The x and y attributes of the filter element along with the width and height, describe the "filter region", the area relative to the filtered element (or in userspace) in which the results of the filter are visible. For more see the web platform docs of the [filter element](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/svg/elements/filter):

Yes, you can vary these from JavaScript, although it's a little unusual to want to do so. You can always just getElementById("f1") to get the filter element and set the x and y that way.

It's a little unclear from your sample code what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The x and the y are the origin of the rendered content of the filter.
If you apply a filter to make a shape shadow, in some case the blur is expanded outside the shape contents and in some case x and y must be negative to show completely the shadow blur generated by the filter.

This code shows a shadow filter created with janvas ([janvas.com](http://www.janvas.com))
if you draw a circle with janvas and publish the svg you will see this svg code into the "def" tag with x and y values to -20%

```
<filter id="_0_" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="200%" height="200%" type="Shadow" shadowoffsetx="5" shadowoffsety="5" shadowblur="5" shadowcolor="rgba(0,0,0,.5)">
<feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="5" dy="5">
</feOffset>
<feColorMatrix result="matrixOut" in="offOut" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0">
</feColorMatrix>
<feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="2">
</feGaussianBlur>
<feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal">
</feBlend>
</filter>
```